# Print a value from a URL string using shell commands

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a URL string (such as `http://10.58.206.10:20002/job-cache/job/548`) in a file. From this string I need to only print the IP address value (i.e, `10.58.206.10`).

This IP address will vary often, so I need to get it like "the value coming after `http://` and before `:20002`". For this I am using `grep` and `sed` as below, but I wasn't able to get the exact value.

```
grep -i "Result URL:" taf.log | sed 's/^.*http://'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid `grep` use a single `sed`:

```
sed -E '/Result URL:/s~.*http://([^:]+):.*~\1~' taf.log
```

Comment: sorry,  its not working.. it is printing total log . Did we miss anything?

Comment: Thanks anubhava! Its working with -nE option. Really it saves lot of time. Thanks alot !!!

Answer (score 0):

This will match exactly the ip address:

```
grep "Result URL" taf.log |egrep -o "([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.){3}[[:digit:]]{1,3}"
```

Edit: This should do it for you. It only prints the ip address when the "Result URL" string is matched.

Comment: Thank you Yakup.. its working. but it is printing twice because this IP will get twice in the log. thats the reason I trying to use grep cmd to get the line from the log which having the name "Result URL" and then using sed.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo http://10.58.206.10:20002/job-cache/job/548 | cut -d"/" -f3 | cut -d":" -f1 >> taf.log
```

It will also work for cases with no port number:

```
echo http://10.58.206.10/job-cache/job/548 | cut -d"/" -f3 | cut -d":" -f1 >> tap.log
```

So its more generalisable. Using sed, echo, tr, xargs and cut together gives you very powerful one liners in bash. xargs being the most powerful for sequential commands.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following also and let me know if this helps.

```
echo "http://10.58.206.10:20002/job-cache/job/548" | awk '{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

Or, if you are reading values from a Input_file then you could try following.

```
awk '{match($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```